# Does kedro support tfrecord?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tfrecord, gcp-ai-platform-training, kedro, tf.data.dataset

To train tensorflow keras models on AI Platform using Docker containers, we convert our raw images stored on GCS to a tfrecord dataset using `tf.data.Dataset`. Thereby the data is never stored locally. Instead the raw images are transformed directly to tfrecords to another bucket. Is it possible to make use of [kedro](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro) with a tfrecord dataset and the streaming capability of `tf.data.Dataset`? According to the [docs](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.html) kedro doesn't seem to support tfrecord datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only TF related dataset we have at the moment is `TensorFlowModelDataset` (https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/kedro/extras/datasets/tensorflow/tensorflow_model_dataset.html), but you can easily [add your own custom dataset](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07_extend_kedro/01_custom_datasets.html#custom-datasets), or please add a feature request/your contribution in [the repo](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/issues)